# need PropertyGrid with drill-down, similar to QuickWatch

Tags: c#

I am trying to display object data members in a generic way.  I started by using PropertyGrid, which satisfies my needs as far as simple properties are concerned.  However, it doesn't let the user drill-down into data members.  It allows browsing into collections, but the interface is a bit awkward.

I'm basically looking for something with the features of QuickWatch.  Does anybody know of any libraries that can do drill-down?

Answer (score 2):

You can drill down into properties in the PropertyGrid of course. This is a vast subject, but maybe your properties simply need to have the ExpandableObjectConverter attached to them? Or if you are going more into details, the attached TypeConverter needs to override the GetPropertiesSupported and GetProperties methods.

There is another way to tell the grid what properties to show underneath a property. You can implement ICustomTypeDescriptor and return your own PropertyDescriptors. But usually this is for more complex scenarios.

Let me know if you need any specific detail on this.

**Update:** in the comments, you asked about displaying a Dictionary. If you want to see each entry of your dict as a subproperty, then this is the complex scenario mentioned above. Your TypeConverter or custom TypeDescriptor will have to generate a PropertyDescriptor for each entry. Its name will be the key and its value will be ... well ... the property value.
If you are new to the PropertyGrid, I encourage you to read a lot about it because it can be quite complex and you will find a good list of resources to start here: [www.propertygridresourcelist.com](http://www.propertygridresourcelist.com)

Comment: Hi Nico,
Thanks, with the ExpandableObjectConverter I can drill-down.  There is only one thing missing - I have some data members that are dictionaries.  It looks like PropertyGrid doesn't support dictionaries at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a treeview control, styled to look like a 'grid'.
Then as you drill down, you can dynamically load any child items that you need to.

Comment: Hi Brian,
I don't really care about how it looks - I just want the functionality.  Hopefully without having to develop it myself.